# Best tips for writing sessions

Tags: publications, writing

I've got a fair amount of writing ahead of me in the coming months and I'm here to ask you all for some strategies for grinding some good writing. I know only of the pomodoro technique, which sometimes works for me, but I'd be curious and eager to hear of any other good tips people here have from their experience. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Separate the writing from the editing.

Comment: Search for _academic writing strategies_ and find some that match your personality and style. Consider Joan Bolker's Writing Your Dissertation in 15 Minutes a Day. (This comment may be removed by a moderator since it recommends a product. I think that the recommendation is reasonable in this case, but understand if it's removed.)

Answer (score 1):

I think one key to successful writing is to make it a regular habit, to lose the  fear of the white page. The pomodoro method is a good start. But anything that helps you to write regularly, even if it is just a few sentences you write every day.
Setting up weekly writing clubs with peers and colleagues during which you concentrate on writing and discuss your progress or difficulties and support each other can also be really helpful.
When I start writing I usually outline my report/paper and generate very detailed headers and section breaks which I then fill with text. It helps focus my thoughts and reduces the feeling of being overwhelmed by the thought of writing a longer piece of work.

Comment: Would add to this that I like the pomodoro method (concentrated bits of focused time with small breaks between), but the alarm from online timers drove me mad. I found a podcast called 'Flow State' where ambient/techno music goes for pomodoro-amounts of time. Helpful for me to encourage focus.